# why am I getting this for only my userid - fatal: not a git repository

Tags: git

Question: Why does git think my userid is not in a git repository when for root (further down) on the same clone directory structure git thinks it is a repository

login as my personal userid

```sh
$ cd /data/cpd-install/git/
$ git clone https://some-path/cpd47x-deployment.git
```

command successfully clones expected files with expected content

```sh
$ cd cpd47x-deployment
$ git status
```

> fatal: not a git repository: '/data/cpd-install/git/cpd47x-deployment'

if I login as root (I would try another userid but don't have one handy)

```sh
$ sudo su - root

$ cd /data/cpd-install/git/cpd47x-deployment
$ git status
```

> On branch main
> Your branch is up to date with origin/main...

Operating System Red Hat Enterprise Linux 8.9

Git version 2.39.3

Reinstalled prior to the commands above git

.git directory contents

```
branches  config  description  HEAD  hooks  index  info  logs  objects  packed-refs  refs
```

Another associate cloned this repository to his workstation and can work with it without error.

So

- valid repository
- clones ok (to several different users)
- root on my machine clones and performs other git commands correctly
- personal userid for associate on another machine clones and performs other git commands correctly
- my userid on this machine clones (gets the files with right content) but cannot issue git status git branch git checkout without the error above "fatal: not a git repository: '/data/cpd-install/git/cpd47x-deployment'"

an explanation of how to fix my userid's behavior so that the git commands will work

drwxr-x---. 8 myuser mygrp   163 Nov 29 18:37 .git

cd .git

ls -la

drwxr-x---. 8 myuser mygrp   163 Nov 29 18:37 .

drwxr-x---. 4 myuser mygrp  4096 Nov 29 18:25 ..

drwxr-x---. 2 myuser mygrp     6 Nov 29 18:24 branches

-rw-r-----. 1 root    root   330 Nov 29 18:25 config

-rw-r-----. 1 myuser mygrp    73 Nov 29 18:24 description

-rw-r-----. 1 root    root    21 Nov 29 18:37 HEAD

drwxr-x---. 2 myuser mygrp  4096 Nov 29 18:24 hooks

-rw-r-----. 1 root    root 10133 Nov 29 18:37 index

drwxr-x---. 2 myuser mygrp    21 Nov 29 18:24 info

drwxr-x---. 3 myuser mygrp    30 Nov 29 18:24 logs

drwxr-x---. 4 myuser mygrp    30 Nov 29 18:24 objects

-rw-r-----. 1 myuser mygrp   179 Nov 29 18:24 packed-refs

drwxr-x---. 5 myuser mygrp    46 Nov 29 18:24 refs

Comment: What permissions are set on the `.git` directory. You could use `ls -la .git` to get a better view

Comment: (you may need to do `sudo ls -la .git` if your user is unable to read the directory)

Comment: info added to main text above

Comment: note the original clone give all files myuser/mygrp.  The root owner/group you see is b/c I have issued commands via root.  I just re-cloned to make sure of that.  And ALL files / folders in .git are myuser/mygrp and the problem repeats... so it's not the root ownership

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It turns out that I have used an environment variable to fix the directory for the repository.  I unset that variable.  And, I had some files owned by root in the related .git directory.  chown -R user:group .....

Problem solved.

Initially, it took comparison between a newly cloned copy and the one I wanted to work with.  Then, we noticed the error message for git status in the new clone was complaining about the other directory.  We started hunting for instances naming that other directory.  One was an environment variable.  Another was in a .config.  Both were eliminated.  Then the new clone gave status while the other did not.  This lead to reviewing the .git directory for permissions.  With different (meaning root) ownership, we adjusted that with the command above.  It started working